# jQuery - How to combine multiple elements with same class name in one selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

Sorry about the cranky title, here's the example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="hey-1-aa"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="hey-2-aa"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hey-1-bb"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hey-2-bb"></tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any better way to selects all the THs/TRs start with the class prefix "hey-2-", with something less verbose than `$('th[class^="hey-2"], td[class^="hey-2"]')`?

Comment: Sorry for the seemingly dumb question, I've updated it a bit to mean what I really would like to know, sorry lol

Comment: In essence, what I would like to know is that, if there is anything like (td, th)[class^="hey-2"] for selectors...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('tr > [class^="hey-2"]')
```

That is, select any children of each tr element that have a class starting with "hey-2".

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CCuxX/

(Or for markup *exactly* like that in the question: `$('tr:odd > *')`)

I know that obviously you've simplified your markup for the question, but as it stands you seem to be using classes as unique identifiers - if so you should use ids.

Answer (score 2):

`$('.hey-2')`

the selectors for [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (the jquery selector engine) begin with basic css and then move from there.  so if you can style an element with a selector, you can grab it from jquery the same way.

for a list of selectors take a look at the [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

### EDIT

so i would think the first thing to eliminate is limiting it to tr/th and just doing something like

`$('table [class^=hey-2]')`

that simplifies it quite a bit.

i tend to agree with the other answers though.  if the items legitimately have something in common, why not give them a common class?  instead of `class="hey-2-aa"` make it `class="hey-2 aa"`  then you really can just use the original answer i posted.

Comment: well, to be fair, if you had turned your comment into an answer i wouldn't have had to write this. ;)

Comment: Sorry for the seemingly dumb question, I've updated it a bit to mean what I really would like to know, sorry lol

Comment: @Kay, sorry for the initial wrong answer.  reading through the original question more carefully i can see my initial answer did not actually meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can use more than 1 class for an element.
So, maybe it would be useful set more classes to the elements.
It will be simpler to select.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="hey-1-aa"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="hey-2-aa sameclass"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hey-1-bb"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hey-2-bb sameclass"></tr>
  </tr>
</table>

$(".sameclass");
```